# how to stop bash from printing alerts?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, script, process

When killing a process with `kill -9 $PID &>/dev/null` in a script, a message is still printed to the terminal after the next command terminates. How do you stop this behaviour?

For example

```
while true; do
    /usr/bin/dostuff -a -b -c
    PID=$(pidof -o %PPID /usr/bin/dostuff)
    sleep 1; 
    kill -KILL $PID &>/dev/null
    echo "hello"
done
```

will print something like

```
hello
./my-cript.sh: line 12:  7134 Killed
/usr/bin/dostuff -a -b -c
```

When I only want it to print "hello"

**EDIT:**
The clean solution is to either run the program in a subshell, or disown it.

```
#SOLUTION
while true; do
    /usr/bin/dostuff -a -b -c &
    disown
    PID=$!
    sleep 1; 
    kill -KILL $PID &>/dev/null
    echo "hello"
done
```

Comment: See: http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html or http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html or http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/

Comment: Why are you even running kill in the background.  In the normal case, kill will return quickly and not need to be backgrounded.  In this case, you are sleeping anyway...so the what's the point?  Just remove the '&'.

Comment: kill isn't being run in the background. `&>` redirects stdin and stdout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output lines aren't redirected to */dev/null* because they aren't *STDOUT/STDERR* from the *kill* process.  They're output from the shell's job control mechanisms.

If you're using *bash*, you could run a *disown* immediately after the job invocation:

```
while true; do
    /usr/bin/dostuff -a -b -c

    ### remove from shell job table
    disown

    PID=$(pidof -o %PPID /usr/bin/dostuff)
    sleep 1; 
    kill -KILL $PID &>/dev/null
    echo "hello"
done
```

I tested this in *bash v3.2.39* on Debian Lenny, with `/bin/sleep 10 &` in place of the above `/usr/bin/dostuff` command:

```
./tmp.sh
hello
hello
hello
hello
^C
```

Comment: cheers ~quack! was just what I was looking for.

Comment: If you run `dostuff` with a trailing `&` then you can get its pid as `$!` (up until you background another process). That will save you the `pidof` lookup... oh yeah, someone already said this.

Answer (score 3):

The error redirection is ineffective because this message is not printed by kill; it is printed by the shell when the background job terminates (I assume a & was missing).

You can avoid this by running in a subshell, using parentheses (but be aware of other potential problems):

```
while true; do
    (
    /usr/bin/dostuff a b c &
    PID=$!
    sleep 1
    kill -9 $PID
    )
    echo hello
done
```

Comment: some executables may put themselves in the background, thus not need the `&`.  but yes, this is another way to handle the issue.

Comment: Sorry Bofh, I tested ~quack's solution first. It works exactly as expected though! +1 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `set -b` and install a trap on SIGCHLD. I think the default SIGCHLD handler is what will (immediately) print the job status to the terminal when you've `set -b`. Here you'd be overriding it.

Comment: yeah, i was wondering if there was a `set` option that would control this behavior.  it's part of the description for `-m` (monitor mode) but setting that doesn't seem to help.  i wasn't able to get rid of it by trapping SIGCHLD either. (tried `trap /bin/true SIGCHLD` but maybe that's not enough.)

Comment: right you are, I just tested a bit myself. I guess disowning is the best option then.