# looking for continuous Screen Capture for retroactivly reproducing errors, timeback machine

Tags: windows, screen-capture, logrotate, lightweight

Usually Screen Video Capturing software are tailored for kind of video producers, who have a plan, have prepared keynotes, etc.

However, I want a "time machine" program for a specific use case:

- Hey, there is a problem with computer/problem! Come and see.
- Oh, indeed, an error. What did you do to come to this error?
- Nothing! I was just working and then suddenly...

What was this "just working" exactly? That is very hard to remember if you was not consciously prepared for it. And you are not, before bug manifests. And when it manifested it often is too late. Sometimes reproducing is easy. But sometimes it requires so fine and rare tweak in workflow - that it just does not register in casual memory. And reproducing that error becomes a search for black cat in dark room.

---

I wonder if there is a video capturing program for Windows that

1. Runs continuously in background, capturing screen, mouse and keyboard. Well, at very least - screen w/o mouse and keyboard.

Webcams, sound - are not needed. Well, maybe sound like standard Windows error beeps, but definitely not microphone sound.

2. Only cares to save last 10-15 minutes. The rest is auto-dropped. Capture should be "rotated" automatically. Until users knocks some obstacle and presses a button to stop dropping and save the recorded buffer persistently.

Basically user should be able to easily record all his activity of TIME PAST.

3. Lightweight, to work on old computers. Yes, really old computers: not much RAM, slow CPU, no SSD, relatively old HDDs (though desktop HDDs seems to be on performance plateau for last 10 years at least).

That is tricky. For example `HuffYUV` codec provides blazing speed by "Huffman compression", so CPU use is minimal. Then, Huffman compression is weak - so the datastream is huge, putting huge burden on RAM volume and HDD throughput.

On the contrary, H.265 would maybe produce minimal datastream (though it is JPEG-like, designed to record natural images rather than desktop programs with their crisp rectangles PNG-like) but at the cost of unbearable CPU consumption.

Maybe there is better codec designed from ground-up for office applications screen captures instead of real world video?
UPD - actually there is, and it is called VNC, TeamViewer, etc...

4. Preferably free to use. It would be good if vendors could suggest this software to their customers, so they could keep it running around clock for weeks until they manage to hit that rare set of conditions triggering the "unreproducible" but recurring error.

Comment: I'm afraid software recs are off-topic on here. I also think your request falls very very close to being 'spyware' & you ought to think very carefully about how this could be misinterpreted &/or misused.

Comment: 1) I came here from google, to the answers exactly like "suggest me screen capture software" though. I can lampshade request for software by asking to introduce a PROCESS of having last 10 minutes of office work always recorded in a loop. And avoiding mentioning a program. But this would be a so obvious "cunning wording" that I prefer to ask bluntly... 2) yes, "timeback machine" always borderlines with spyware. Actually - any screenshot/screencast program is a spyware to a degree. What makes the difference is user's explicit action to SAVE the log. Otherwise 10 minutes later it would be gone.

Comment: This question would be a dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/108034/rolling-desktop-recorder but as the rules changed several years ago, it was also closed as off-topic

Comment: Thank you for the link! because there is no One True Term and I missed the "rolling" word in search

Comment: Okay, feel free to report dup and close :-D